# Does Google Chrome have APIs to access its downloads page?

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Am I able to "tap into" Google Chrome's Downloads page through an extension/add-on? I want to write an extension that needs the file names (or paths) of all the files that are currently being downloaded by the user. Will this possible? What APIs should I be looking at? It is quite tricky to search for this and I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late but I think it is possible now with the `chrome.downloads` API:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html

Answer (score 3):

No I can not find a Google Chrome API that will allow you to see the files that are currently being downloaded.

There are a number of experimental APIs, that alow deep integration with the browser here bt none that provide the information you require:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.html

Comment: Does anyone know if this has been added yet?

Answer (score 2):

Not until Chrome 30.

http://peter.sh/2013/08/webgl-and-device-motion-for-android-port-forwarding-and-named-grid-areas/

It looks like Chrome extensions download's api will be released with chrome 30, and has been marked stable according to Peter Beverloo's blog.