# How to find currently active downloads in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there a way to find currently active http connections in a page? For example, a video that is currently being played (either html5 video or flash), large objects or even websocket connections?

Comment: In which browser do you want to do this? Answer to this question is browser specific. You can do something like this, only through the browser API.

Comment: Honestly, I'd take any major browser, but what am I looking for here? I'm lacking the proper search keywords to find anything - there simply is too much noise around "javascript" "active" and "download"...

Comment: ok, I got the point. Check my answer below and go to the links provided. Here what you should do is, finding methods of browser API that support to access downloads page (I have provided a link). Then find the way of calling browser API using javascript. Then you can do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767920/does-google-chrome-have-apis-to-access-its-downloads-page) StackOverflow question, you will see that google chrome does not support to access its download page.

But I found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozmill_Tests/Shared_Modules/DownloadsAPI/downloadManager) firefox API that supports to access its download manager window. There you will see methods like, getAllDownloads() and getDownloadState(). You can call these methods using Javascript and get the job done.

Is it clear enough?

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I had bookmarklet injected js in mind though, I'd like to find the current playing video url without much hassle ... but that seems to be a futile quest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, unless you manually keep track of all these connections.

(for some reason I can't add comments, so editing this answer).

With manually I meant, before you make any connection you update a javascript object somewhere. After the connection is closed, trigger another event.